# PHP integrer removing zero from the start of integer

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Remove the preceding zero from a string

> 000001 to 000010

It stores the following values

> 00001, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10

But I want something like this.

> 00001, 00002, 00003, 00004, 00005, 00006, 00007, 00008, 00009, 000010

The algorithm is removing those zeros from start.
Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: "you are trying" lets show code

Comment: _The algorithm is removing those zeros_ What algorithm? And why would you need any leading zeroes?

Comment: Remove zeros or adding zeros ? Try `str_pad()`

Comment: In the integer value 001, the 00 is redundant, why it removes it. If you wish to store it as 001, you should store it as a string.

Comment: I want those zeros because they are the part of the serial of some products

Comment: I can't store it as string. the complete scenario is this that user will enter the starting serial and ending serial and all the products were saved into the database with the increment of 1 in each product.
so if I use string then I can't add 1 into it

Comment: a number where leading zeroes are significant is *not* an integer, but is a *numeric string* instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one's easy! Try this:

```
<?php

$num = 5;
echo str_pad($num, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Outputs 000005

See it here https://3v4l.org/0Fgdp

Comment: Thanks this just so the trick

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you mark this as the correct answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If no of zeros are fixed then:

```
str_pad($your_no, $total_no_of_digits, $string_to_append, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

else, you can use the associative array to define no of zeros then use `str_pad()`

Comment: _If no of zeros are fixed_ What does that mean? Also please reformat your answer.

Comment: He means to say that if the number of zeros in each serial is fixed and in my case number of zeros are fixed

Comment: My bad.. as per your question the best solution is to use str_pad()